# Each user and their role in every database on the server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, security

How do I get each user and their role in every database on the server?

I figure I'd start with this:

```
    SELECT *
FROM sys.database_role_members drm
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals rp ON drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals mp ON drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    SERVER VARCHAR(100),
    db_name VARCHAR(100),
    db_role VARCHAR(100),
    db_user VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @table
EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
    USE [?];

    SELECT @@SERVERNAME SERVER,
        ''?'' db,
        rp.NAME AS database_role,
        mp.NAME AS database_user
    FROM sys.database_role_members drm
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals rp ON drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals mp ON drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id
    ORDER BY 3
'


SELECT SERVER,
    db_role,
    db_user,
    db_name
FROM @table
WHERE db_name NOT IN (
        'master',
        'tempdb',
        'model',
        'msdb',
        'DBA_UTIL'
        )
ORDER BY 4 DESC,
    2
```

Comment: [Just to explain why this is getting down-voted](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/). "Noobs" won't realize that this undocumented, unsupported stored procedure can skip databases with no indication whatsoever.

Comment: `sp_msforeachdb` is bad. Why you might ask? [This link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-part-2/). It's written by some guy name Aaron Bertrand. I hear he drives a Mercedes.

Comment: This is why I hate you guys.  And you're absolutely right about the SP and I knew / know that every time I use it.

Comment: @DanAndrews for someone who *"believe in the teachings of Jesus"*, hate is a strong word. I'm deeply offended.

Comment: Seriously @DanAndrews I wouldn't recommend using that the proc Aaron blogged about works much better.

Comment: @DanAndrews and I know all about CTEs. Yet you attacked me for showing a "noob" as you called him how to solve a simple problem with a simple CTE, because CTE syntax is "too hard." Yet here you are demonstrating a very brittle, undocumented and unsupported stored procedure that almost certainly *will* bite users, noob or not, and they may not even notice when it happens. This is called a double standard.

Comment: Then why is it even on this site? Because it will benefit ***other readers***. If you don't care to warn other readers about the things you know but they might not, take it down.