# sp_addrolemember and sp_droprolemember - is there a 'sp_isrolemember'?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, role

Setting up SQLServer with XA Drivers contains a step where you must assign users to the role called "SqlJDBCXAUser"; this can be done using "sp_addrolemember" sproc and undone using the "sp_droprolemember".

Is there a way of checking whether a particular user has been assigned that role ?

Or (better): a way of just listing ALL users assigned to use the specific role here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IS_MEMBER`

See the manual here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186271.aspx

To list members, use `sp_helprolemember` or see [How to list role members in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971272/how-to-list-role-members-in-sql-server-2008-r2)